# Can't change version with n

Tags: node.js

I have first installed npm via the ubuntu package manager (ubuntu 12).
It installed a first node version.
Then I installed n, and two different versions with n.
However when I type n instead of the choice for a version I have the following line :
`/home/vagrant/bin/node`
Any idea ?

Edit : The result of n ls :

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ n ls
/home/vagrant/bin/node

0.8.6
0.8.7
0.8.8
0.8.9
0.8.10
0.8.11
0.8.12
0.8.13
0.8.14
0.8.15
0.8.16
0.8.17
0.8.18
0.8.19
0.8.20
0.8.21
0.8.22
0.8.23
0.8.24
0.8.25
0.8.26
0.9.0
0.9.1
0.9.2
0.9.3
0.9.4
0.9.5
0.9.6
0.9.7
0.9.8
0.9.9
0.9.10
0.9.11
0.9.12
0.10.0
0.10.1
0.10.2
0.10.3
0.10.4
0.10.5
0.10.6
0.10.7
0.10.8
0.10.9
0.10.10
0.10.11
0.10.12
0.10.13
0.10.14
0.10.15
0.10.16
0.10.17
0.10.18
0.10.19
ο **0.10.20** 
0.10.21
0.11.0
0.11.1
0.11.2
0.11.3
0.11.4
0.11.5
0.11.6
**0.11.7**
```

when I do node --version I have this result:

```
v0.10.20
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `n ls`?

Comment: @enducat : I have added the result of n ls to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo n stable
```

or

```
$ sudo n latest
```

or

```
$ sudo n <VersionNumber>

$ n
```

select the version with the arrow and hit Enter
exit the terminal and open it agina.